# Ignore initial run of effect()

Tags: angular, angular-signals

we have:

```
effect(() => {
  console.log(`Value is ${newValue()}`);
});
```

We don't want whole `console.log` to run on initial signal set. We want it to run only starting with 2nd change of the signal.

Should we have a private field `initialRun` (`true` initially) in our component and set it to `false` at the end of our `effect()` code so that each subsequent run actually executes `!initialRun && console.log(....)`?

Or is there any smarter way?

Comment: This is currently being discussed : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54372